# Bold font in javascript text function

Tags: javascript, string

I would normally use the `<b>` tag or `string.bold()` to make the font bold in javascript. However I am coming across an issue where a certain function isn't taking html tags.

If I try `<b>` it will show up in the test example. If I try `string.bold()` instead of the font being bold you will see `<b>` wrapped around the text.

I noticed that the new line `\` didn't work as well but `\n` did work. When I looked it up, `\n` is a special character for new lines. However I didn't see any special characters for bold.

How can I make the follow code show bold?

```
### Code
Office.context.mailbox.item.setSelectedDataAsync("Hello " + msgTodisplayname[0] +
",\n\
<b>this is a test to make the font bold</b>", function(asyncResult) {})
```

Here is a picture of the code in question:
[image]

Here is a picture of the result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're missing an argument in your function. '{coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html}'

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(
   'Hello' + displayName + '\n<b>My bold text</b>',
   {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html},
   function(asyncResult) {}
)
```

Comment: That was so quick and painless. Thank you!